# Can't reach to specific xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I want to reach x:Property nodes and their attributes:

Xml:

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap" x:Class="WebApplication3.work" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic;assembly=System" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System" xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:s4="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.ServiceModel" xmlns:sa="clr-namespace:System.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sad="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System" xmlns:scg1="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.ServiceModel" xmlns:scg2="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:scg3="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data" xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:st="clr-namespace:System.Text;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <x:Members>
     <x:Property Name="number1" Type="InArgument(x:Int32)" />
     <x:Property Name="number2" Type="InArgument(x:Int32)" />
     <x:Property Name="total" Type="OutArgument(x:Int32)" />
  </x:Members>
.......
</Activity>
```

C# Code:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filePath);

        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
        XmlNodeList elements = doc.SelectNodes("//Activity/x:Members/x:Property",manager);
```

Unfortunately elements variable returns with 0 node. Can you help me?

Comment: Shouldn't you select `("/Activity/x:Members")` node and then look for its ChildNodes?

Comment: Looks like `Activity` element is defined with a namespace, so you may need to add that namespace to the manager and modify your xpath to match against it.

Comment: Someone offered GetElementsByTagName("x:Property"); and deleted his post. It works like this, but Could this cause problem?

Comment: Why don't you use LINQ-to-XML? Are you on .NET 2 or lower?

Comment: I'm using .Net 4, but I don't have any experience with LINQ but I will check it too. Thanks

Comment: I suggest using LINQ-to-XML as it is easier to use and code is shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and a very slight correction of your code that makes it select the wanted nodes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("x:Property");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var xdocument = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var xname = XName.Get("Property", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
var propertyNodes = xdocument.Descendants(xname).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that the document is in a default namespace**.

In your XPath expression:

```
//Activity/x:Members/x:Property
```

the name `Activity` is unprefixed and is considered by XPath to be in "no namespace".

The XPath evaluator is trying to find all `Activity` elements in the document that are in "no namespace" and fails -- hence the 0 results.

**The solution is easy**:

Just add this line to your code:

```
manager.AddNamespace("def", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities");
```

**then evaluate this XPath expression**:

```
 XmlNodeList elements = doc.SelectNodes("//def:Activity/x:Members/x:Property",manager);
```